# foldl behaviour on infinite lists

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, fold

What I've understood about foldl vs. foldr on lists :

If we **right** fold **[0,1,2,3]** with a function **s** and a starting accumulator **a**, we are doing this :

`f 0 (f 1 (f 2 (f 3 a)))`

If we **left** fold **[0,1,2,3]** with a function **s** and a starting accumulator **a**, we are doing this :

`f (f (f (f 0 a) 1) 2) 3)`

---

Given :

```
elem_r :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Bool
elem_r y ys = foldr (\x acc -> if x == y then True else acc) False ys
```

and

```
elem_l :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Bool
elem_l y ys = foldl (\acc x -> if x == y then True else acc) False ys
```

It seems clear to me that `elem_r 3 [0..]` will compute what it really must, and return True as soon as value **3** is reached.

`f 0 (f 1 (f 2 (f 3 (...)))`

Whereas `elem_l 3 [0..]` need to evaluate the complete nested functions application before returning a result.

`f (f (f (f (f 0 3) 1) 2) 3) ...)`

---

Now my question is :

In the specific case of `elem_l 0 [0..]` 
The searched element is the **first item of the list**.

In this expression :
`f (f (f (f (f 0 0) 1) 2) 3) ...)`
The innermost function (f 0 0) can immediately be evaluated to "True".
Why does Haskell continue to evaluate the rest of nested functions?

Comment: `if x == y then True else acc` could be a bit tidier as `acc || x == y`, imho.

Comment: Recommended reading: https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl'

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz you meant `x == y || acc`, undoubtedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `f (f (f (f (f 0 0) 1) 2) 3) ...)` is not right. The final parenthesis and the first `f` are mismatched, and the initial argument is all wrong. It really is

```
(f ... (f (f (f (f False 0) 1) 2) 3) ...)
```

so after `foldl` has finished building this expression (which is, *never*), we have to get through an infinite amount of nested expressions, evaluating *them* first, before we get to the innermost expression, which gets evaluated *last* (because `f` stops on 0). Or in this case, *never*.

And the other test, searching for 3, would stop earlier, on `(f (f (f (f False 0) 1) 2) 3)`, because now `f` stops on 3; but still it'd have to go through the *infinite* amount of nested expressions first, after that *infinite* nested expression is built.

Answer (score 7):

Even if you "immediately" reduce `f 0 0` to `True`, that does not help. You still have all the surrounding occurrences of `f` to reduce ...